# ORA-22291: Open LOBs exist at transaction commit time

Tags: oracle

why is that, when i want to write out a resultset into a BLOB
im getting "ORA-22291: Open LOBs exist at transaction commit time"
when the resulset is empty.
But I have

```
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(myFile);
DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(myBlob);

COMMIT;
```

lines too

Edit:
i have debugged maybe the source issue in here, the DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(myFile) is 0. That gives ORA:21560, why is that an error?

```
DBMS_LOB.LOADFROMFILE(DEST_LOB => myBlob,
                      SRC_LOB  => myFile,
                      AMOUNT   => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(myFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

You must close the LOBs **before** committing the transaction.

Comment: i do, see above , im using DBMS_LOB.CLOSE

Comment: I saw it but I remarked the **before** word. Now you edited and put the commit which was not there when I answered. The problem is the close is not working. See http://www.orasite.com/errores/ORA/ORA-22291 or http://psoug.org/oraerror/ORA-22291.htm